# ERROR[12799] netsock2.c: getaddrinfo("ims.ntc.net.np", "(null)", ...): Name or service not known, How can i resolve this issue?

Tags: asterisk, sip, voip, pjsip

I am trying to configure NTC SIP Line Trunk configuration but " ERROR[12799] netsock2.c: getaddrinfo("ims.ntc.net.np", "(null)", ...): Name or service not known" error occur. Telecom said that our sip request not reaching there, How can i resolve this issue ?

```
[2020-07-24 07:59:05] ERROR[12799] netsock2.c: getaddrinfo("ims.ntc.net.np", "(null)", ...): Name or service not known
[2020-07-24 07:59:05] WARNING[12799] acl.c: Unable to lookup 'ims.ntc.net.np'
[2020-07-24 07:59:05] WARNING[12799] acl.c: Cannot connect to (null): Invalid argument
[2020-07-24 07:59:05] WARNING[12799] chan_sip.c: sip_xmit of 0x7f93981e0960 (len 433) to (null) returned -1: Invalid argument
[2020-07-24 07:59:05] NOTICE[12799] chan_sip.c: -- Registration for '+97723597002@ims.ntc.net.np' timed out, trying again (Attempt #14)
[2020-07-24 07:59:05] WARNING[12799] chan_sip.c: Retransmission timeout reached on transmission 63c184f060c6ddd85c43e1b75b3aec3f@127.0.0.1 for seqno 114 (Critical Request) -- See https://wiki.asterisk.org/wiki/display/AST/SIP+Retransmissions
Packet timed out after 60031ms with no response
[2020-07-24 07:59:06] WARNING[12799] chan_sip.c: sip_xmit of 0x7f93981e0960 (len 433) to (null) returned -1: Invalid argument
[2020-07-24 07:59:07] WARNING[12799] chan_sip.c: sip_xmit of 0x7f93981e0960 (len 433) to (null) returned -1: Invalid argument
[2020-07-24 07:59:09] WARNING[12799] chan_sip.c: sip_xmit of 0x7f93981e0960 (len 433) to (null) returned -1: Invalid argument
[2020-07-24 07:59:13] WARNING[12799] chan_sip.c: sip_xmit of 0x7f93981e0960 (len 433) to (null) returned -1: Invalid argument
[2020-07-24 07:59:17] WARNING[12799] chan_sip.c: sip_xmit of 0x7f93981e0960 (len 433) to (null) returned -1: Invalid argument
[2020-07-24 07:59:21] WARNING[12799] chan_sip.c: sip_xmit of 0x7f93981e0960 (len 433) to (null) returned -1: Invalid argument
[2020-07-24 07:59:25] WARNING[12799] chan_sip.c: sip_xmit of 0x7f93981e0960 (len 433) to (null) returned -1: Invalid argument
[2020-07-24 08:00:05] ERROR[12799] netsock2.c: getaddrinfo("ims.ntc.net.np", "(null)", ...): Name or service not known
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a DNS Looukup error.

If you are using this DNS in any trunk configuration this is the source of the problem, map using and IP directly and you will have no more errors.

But if the trunk is using an IP I suggest you to map this domain. The provider can use an internal domain in the request and this can trow an error.

Check too if there's no firewall blocking the communication.

Answer (score -1):

You are using somewhere trunk host name "ims.ntc.net.np" and that dns name is invalid.

Check name or ensure dns works okay.